# Print only the value of the array

Tags: php, printing, echo

i have an array in PHP and i want to print the content of it.
My array has 3 entries :

```
610,  
609,  
608
```

when i print it with

```
print_r($ar_par[$i]);
```

the result i get is this:

[image]

What i want, is to print only the numbers.
How can i do this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract each of the `telos` values from your array. To output the value as an array, you can use

```
print_r(array_column($ar_par, 'telos'));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 610 [1] => 609 [2] => 608 )
```

Or to output the individual values:

```
foreach (array_column($ar_par, 'telos') as $telos) {
    echo "$telos\n";
}
```

Output:

```
610
609
608
```

Or a comma separated list:

```
echo implode(',', array_column($ar_par, 'telos'));
```

Output:

```
610,609,608
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WTOIA)

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, but what if i want to print one value at a time for example i want to prin : "SOMETHING HERE 610 SOMETHING ELSE"
"SOMETHING HERE 608 SOMETHING ELSE"
"SOMETHING HERE 609 SOMETHING ELSE"

Comment: @Aleksander do you want to print the same thing for each value?

Comment: i have a program where  at one point i am using FOREACH to print another array, but i want to print the value of the array above also

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n0bjhl heres aprint screen of my code
the arrow shows where i want to print the value of the array

Comment: @Aleksander you probably just want to replace `$num = $ar_par[$i];` with `$num = $ar_par[$i]['telos'];`

Comment: @Aleksander no worries. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

use implode for it.

```
$string=implode(",",$telos);
 print_r($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `array_values()`

It will not print array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there it's very simple you can use `foreach` loop

```
foreach($ar_par as $key => $value)
{
    // $value is what you needed :)
    echo $key." has the value". $value;
}
```